# Kotlin get function. Should be simple but I don't know how. Any assistance would be appreciated

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

Good day. So I came from java and now doing kotlin. What I want is very simple but I cant seem to get it right.

```
        var j: Int = 4
   
    for (i in 0 until movieList.size) {

        sum += movieList.get(i)(j)
     //Answer from @lukas.j - It was as simple as sum +=  movieList[i].Weight

    }
```

I first tried it without the .get,  then I saw it didn't understand what I was talking about so google told me to use .get.

This is probably a simple fix if someone can just show me how please. The array is a 2d array list.

[I tried a suggestion and this error shows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxvEL.png)

[Another example of a different attempt with a different error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqlQp.png)

Adding my array:

```
val movieList = ArrayList<MovieModel>().apply {


    add(MovieModel(190617, 182832, "Jcorp", 100,"Delivery done", "Delivery not done",""))
    add(MovieModel(190617, 182833, "Honda", 100,"No exceptions", "Exceptions",""))
    add(MovieModel(190617, 182832, "Everflu", 100,"100%", "50%",""))
    add(MovieModel(190617, 182832, "Panado", 100,"OK", "NO",""))
    add(MovieModel(190617, 182832, "Gheiters", 100,"Success", "Failed",""))
    add(MovieModel(190617, 182832, "John", 100,"Yes", "No",""))
    add(MovieModel(190617, 182832, "Everflu", 100,"false", "false",""))
    add(MovieModel(190617, 182832, "Everflu", 100,"false", "false",""))
    add(MovieModel(190617, 182832, "Everflu", 100,"false", "false",""))
    add(MovieModel(9190617, 182832, "Everflu", 100,"false", "false",""))
    add(MovieModel(190617, 182832, "Everflu", 100,"false", "false",""))
    add(MovieModel(190617, 182832, "Everflu", 100,"false", "false",""))
    add(MovieModel(190617, 182832, "Everflu", 100,"false", "false",""))
    add(MovieModel(190617, 182832, "Everflu", 100,"false", "false",""))
    add(MovieModel(190617, 182832, "Everflu", 100,"false", "false",""))
    add(MovieModel(190617, 182832, "Everflu", 100,"false", "false",""))
    add(MovieModel(190617, 182832, "Everflu", 100,"false", "false",""))
    add(MovieModel(190617, 182832, "Everflu", 100,"false", "false",""))
    add(MovieModel(190617, 182832, "Everflu", 100,"false", "false",""))
    add(MovieModel(10, 182832, "Everflu", 100,"false", "false",""))
    add(MovieModel(10, 182832, "2010", 100,"false", "false",""))
    add(MovieModel(10, 182832, "2010", 100,"false", "false",""))
    add(MovieModel(10, 182832, "2010", 100,"false", "false",""))
    add(MovieModel(10, 182832, "2010", 100,"false", "false",""))
    add(MovieModel(10, 182832, "2010", 100,"false", "false",""))
    add(MovieModel(10, 182832, "2010", 100,"false", "false",""))
    add(MovieModel(10, 182832, "2010", 100,"false", "false",""))

 }
```

Movie model:

```
    package com.dispatch.tripsheet

class MovieModel(
    var WOrder: Int,
    var DElNote: Int,
    var Company: String,
    var Weight: Int,
    var Button1: String,
    var Button2: String,
    var tvdone: String

    )
```

Comment: Quote: _The array is a 2d array list._ Not as per the photo you posted. It is an _ArrayList_ of _MovieModel_.

Comment: @lukas.j I added the code of my array. I think it is a 2d array list, but I can be wrong.

Comment: So with _movieList[i]_ you get a movie. Then what are you trying to access with _j_?

Comment: @lukas.j With j  I aim to get the value which are currently a static 100. These values will change later so I am trying to  get to the 4th index point of each row. And then add these values.

Comment: What is _MovieModel_? A typealias? A class? A data class? Something else? Because obviously it (currently) doesn't support indexed access.

Comment: @lukas.j I added my moviemodel. Let me know if it helps or do you need more information.

Comment: You access Weight like this: _val weight = movie.Weight_

Comment: @lukas.j Thank you I will try this. Is this a line of code I add in my current class or create a new sub class?

Comment: I just posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use a data class instead of a class:

```
data class MovieModel(
  var WOrder: Int,
  var DElNote: Int,
  var Company: String,
  var Weight: Int,
  var Button1: String,
  var Button2: String,
  var tvdone: String
)
```

Creating the list can be done with *listOf:*

```
val movieList = listOf(
  MovieModel(190617, 182832, "Jcorp", 100, "Delivery done", "Delivery not done", ""),
  MovieModel(190617, 182833, "Honda", 100, "No exceptions", "Exceptions", ""),
  MovieModel(190617, 182832, "Jcorp", 100, "Delivery done", "Delivery not done", "")
)
```

And you can get and set the weight like this:

```
val movie = movieList[0]
println(movie.Weight)   // Output: 100

movie.Weight = 125
println(movie.Weight)   // Output: 125
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you're looking for is (see [Indexed access operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#indexed-access-operator)):

```
movieList[i][j]
```

Alternatively, you may use the `get` syntax:

```
movieList.get(i).get(j)
```

However this feels unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: Sadly it didn't solve my problem. I added some photos to help.

Comment: As @lukas.j mentioned in a comment on the original post, `movieList` is not a 2d list, hence the "[i][j]" syntax does not work. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to add up the total weight of the cargo. The values are still static - I am still going to import them from a database. So the values will change and I am trying to get code that will go to the index position and get the weight value.